# Copying grease pencil strokes from one project to another

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I have a problem with copying grease pencil strokes to other projects in Blender.

I cannot append files, as the strokes are lost and I cannot even edit them.

How can I copy and paste grease pencil strokes, so I can edit them freely in another projects? I am making 2D animation, so I need to copy some characters, places and so on.

Comment: you'll need to append the gp objects into your new file

Comment: Appending works just fine, I usually append whole characters complete with armatures to my projects. If you are trying to append objects, try instead to put your object(s) in a collection and append the collection.